# How to post a json for a particular parameter using CURL

Tags: json, curl

I try to do a POST request which contains number of parameters. One parameetr require a JSON file. I tried several options but i face issue with json. The parameter which requires json is `'swagger'`..
Here is the curl request I try.[1] But looks like this is not accepted by server. Im getting following error;

```
"null is not supported"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: swaggerimpl.json
```

How can i post the JSON using curl for a particular parameter?

```
[1]

curl -X POST -b  cookies $SERVER/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag -d "action=implement&name=YoutubeFeeds&visibility=public&version=1.0.0&provider=admin&endpoint_type=http&implementation_methods=http&wsdl=&wadl=&endpointType=nonsecured&production_endpoints=http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds&implementation_methods=endpoint" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 'swagger=' @swaggerimpl.json
```

**Edit :**

**Curl Command**

```
curl -X POST -b  cookies $SERVER/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag -d "action=implement&name=YoutubeFeeds&visibility=public&version=1.0.0&provider=admin&endpoint_type=http&implementation_methods=http&wsdl=&wadl=&endpointType=nonsecured&production_endpoints=http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds&implementation_methods=endpoint" -d @swagger_impl.json -d @endpointconfig_impl.json;
```

**Error;**
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

**The suspect json file**

```
swagger={
    "apiVersion": "1.0.0",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
    "authorizations": {
        "oauth2": {
            "scopes": [],
            "type": "oauth2"
        }
    },
.........
}
```

**The cast code:**

```
public static boolean jsFunction_updateAPIImplementation(Context cx, Scriptable thisObj,
                                            Object[] args,  Function funObj) throws Exception, ScriptException {
        boolean success = false;

        if (args==null||args.length == 0) {
            handleException("Invalid number of input parameters.");
        }

        NativeObject apiData = (NativeObject) args[0]; //This cause issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter that you are adding at the end should not contain the space. But if you remove this space then '@swagger.json' will be added as a test (not the file content). If you want to pass JSON as a parameter then you can add to the file parameter name like:
swagger={..}

It looks like workaround but curl will merge every -d parameter into the request parameters and it doesn't allow unquoted spaces.

Comment: $SERVER -- can you post value of it

Comment: //SERVER=http://localhost:9763 // , Im using MAC. and i tried simple curl request and try to intercept that -d is working or not in mac, with tcpmon, //curl localhost:6666/ -H "Content-type:application/json" -X POST -d @swaggerimpl.json;// but i do not see any message body in the tcpmon window

Comment: If you use -vX then it will show the request information. Can you post it? "curl -vX POST ..."

Comment: I've updated the response. Try to add parameterName= into the file

Comment: Thanks that works..Now one issue; it reads my json, but my backend throws this error;//org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String//. My json has some arrays and all..I dont have control to edit my javasctript code..Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: it is hard to say without seen JSON and how cast it :).