# org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined

Tags: javascript, json, curl

When i do POST (a json string) using curl i'm getting following error[1];
Anybody knows, how to fix this?
I post my json as `-d @endpointconfigimpl.json` and the file content is like;

```
endpoint_config='{
    "production_endpoints": {
        "url": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds",
        "config": null
    },
    "endpoint_type": "http"
}'
```

> [1] Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property "length" from undefined
>   (/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag#11)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)

Comment: In the `JSON format` there is no `=` characters

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik in my curl request i need to pass number of parameters. Only for one parameter i need to pass json. That is why i included that in the file as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243046/how-to-post-a-json-for-a-particular-parameter-using-curl

Comment: give a look to this https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request